# Python - Explicit Implementation of two abstract classes with same abstract method name

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement two abstract classes in one class, but the two abstract classes contain abstract methods with the same name.  In C#, I would be able to explicitly implement the abstract methods allowing them to be called on the context of the type.  Is there a way to do something similar in python to allow for both abstract classes to be implemented?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from builtins import str


class AbstractConfig1(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def unique_prop(self) -> str:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod 
    def output_filepath(self) -> str:  ## same name in AbstractConfig2
        pass


class AbstractConfig2(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def other_unique_prop(self) -> str:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def output_filepath(self) -> str: ## same name in AbstractConfig1
        pass


class Config(AbstractConfig1, AbstractConfig2):
    def __init__(self,
                 unique_prop:str,
                 other_unique_prop:str,
                 config1_output_filepath: str,
                 config2_output_filepath: str
                 ):
        self._unique_prop = unique_prop
        self._other_unique_prop = other_unique_prop
        self._config1_output_filepath = config1_output_filepath
        self._config2_output_filepath = config2_output_filepath

    @property
    def unique_prop(self) -> str:
        return  self._unique_prop

    @property
    def other_unique_prop(self) -> str:
        return self._other_unique_prop

    @property
    def AbstractConfig1.output_filepath(self) -> str:  ## How I would explicitly implement this in C#
        return self._config1_output_filepath


    @property
    def AbstractConfig2.output_filepath(self) -> str:  ## How I would explicitly implement this in C#
        return self._config2_output_filepath
```

Here is a link to what I'm attempting in terms of C#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

---

Edit to clear things up a little more:

I simplified this a little more than what my code is doing, instead of just passing through a string, the abstract methods I named `output_filepath` are returning objects built in the `Config` class.  But I will continue using str in the example to simplify.

Essentially the `Config` class is acting as a facade to multiple `AbstractConfig` classes.  This way, the facade `Config` can be configured and then passed to initialize other objects.  This would look a bit like below:

```py
class ClassUsingAbstractConfig1:
    def __init__(self, config: AbstractConfig1):
        self.config = config

    def output_file(self):
        path = self.config.output_filepath
        # this object outputs to one filepath

class ClassUsingAbstractConfig2:
    def __init__(self, config: AbstractConfig2):
        self.config = config

    def output_file(self):
        path = self.config.output_filepath
        # this object outputs to another filepath
        
config = Config("prop", 
                "prop2", 
                "filepath1", 
                "filepath2")
class1 = ClassUsingAbstractConfig1(config)
class2 = ClassUsingAbstractConfig2(config)
class1.output_file()  # outputs to filepath1
class2.output_file()  # outputs to filepath2
```

And it may just be that python won't allow this and I need to take a different approach.

Comment: What's the difference between `AbstractConfig1.output_filepath` and `AbstractConfig2.output_filepath` supposed to be? Classes cannot inherit from other classes in a vacuum. `Config` only gets *one* `output_filepath`.

Comment: `output_filepath` would return a different value depending on whether the instantiation of `Config` was acting as an `AbstractConfig1` type or as a `AbstractConfig2` type.  I added a little more info to the question... but as I'm typing this out, it may be a feature of typed languages that's not in python.

Comment: Python is typed (and quite strongly). It's just *dynamically* typed, not statically typed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself: "What is the signature of `string: Config::output_filepath(Config: self)`"

What you're referring to is the [Multiple inheritance - Diamond Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20Diamond%20Problem,from%20both%20Class2%20and%20Class3.). Basically, ***the `class`: `Config` can have only 1 implementation for the method (function) with the same signature***. You have to imagine that each function uses its signature as the index for the function call table. This is how you call a function from one class to another, especially when they share the same name. But in your case it shares the same [`signature`](https://python-forge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signature.html.).

As a consequence, I think you'll have something like:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from builtins import str


class AbstractConfig1(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def unique_prop(self) -> str:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod 
    def output_filepath(self) -> str:  ## same name in AbstractConfig2
        pass


class AbstractConfig2(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def other_unique_prop(self) -> str:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def output_filepath(self) -> str: ## same name in AbstractConfig1
        pass


class Config(AbstractConfig1, AbstractConfig2):
    def __init__(self,
                 unique_prop:str,
                 other_unique_prop:str,
                 config1_output_filepath: str,
                 config2_output_filepath: str
                 ):
        self._unique_prop = unique_prop
        self._other_unique_prop = other_unique_prop
        self._config1_output_filepath = config1_output_filepath
        self._config2_output_filepath = config2_output_filepath

    @property
    def unique_prop(self) -> str:
        return  self._unique_prop

    @property
    def other_unique_prop(self) -> str:
        return self._other_unique_prop

    @property
    def output_filepath(self) -> str:
        # or whatever the implementation you want to be.
        return self._config1_output_filepath + self._config2_output_filepath
```

This problem exists in virtually all high level languages and is related to the concept of `Class` and `Function` and how that ends up being translated on the Language Virtual Machine (if is a C#, Java, Python etc.) all the way to the `kernel` and CPU to be loaded and executed (other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217334/best-way-of-solving-diamond-problem-in-python-with-fields))

Comment: I think the problem is that `output_filepath` isn't supposed to combine two paths; `Config` is somehow supposed to inherit each `output_filepath` *separately*.

Comment: If that's the case, the answer is: ***Basically, the class: Config can have only 1 implementation for the method (function) with the same signature.***. Should have made that with bold in the answer, I think. ?!?

Comment: Yeah, the rest of your answer basically does not apply to the question. In Python, it's not even about the signature, as Python doesn't have overloading.

Comment: True. My argument was related to the diamond problem. There are differences between languages, true.